# Hosting Nodejs application without port

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, hosting

I have a nodejs application running on port 3000. I wanted to host it on Linux environment. So I installed nodejs in it. It's working fine but I should specify the port each time.

example: `mydomain.net:3000/url_i_want`,

How can I avoid this. and also when running my app like that, all users are kind of connected to each others. If one of them disconnect all other users are. If one of them change page all others have there pages changing. Is it because they are all listening to the same port `3000` ? I searched and found that it can be related to `PM2` and `Nginx`. Is it the solution ?

Comment: I can't see how this is related to reactjs which is in your tags.

Comment: 1) Look up port forwarding. 2) If one disconnecting knocks everyone else out, you have a problem with your coding.

Comment: @VincasStonys my front is with react and flux.

Comment: @Scimonster  connecting is just an example of an action.. it's the same for all actions. my code is fine. but i'm wondering if i should install soemthing with express to make it work as with a cluster...

Comment: If any action applies to all users, that means your code is not fine.

Comment: no it's not related: for example to disconnect:   here is the request:  'UPDATE `user'` SET `token` = 0 where `user_id` ='+id;   and the id i get it from the request.... means it's impossible ... and i verify directly on the database and it's all fine...

Comment: If all the users are seeing the same page, it can be bug in the way in which you determine `user_id` of the request. Can you check for the hard coded value or the logic in which you determine the `user_id`?

Answer (score 10):

Whenever you load a URL without specifying the port number, the browser defaults to 80, because 80 is the default port number for HTTP.

So if you load `http://stackoverflow.com/questions`, the browser "converts" it to `http://stackoverflow.com:80/questions`.

If you don't want a port number to be specified to access your website, your app should be listening on port 80, instead of 3000.

However, it is not recommended for Node apps to directly listen on port 80 (although they very well can).

What you can do is use a front-facing proxy such as `nginx`, which accepts connections to the host's port 80, and then redirects the request to `localhost:3000`, where your app is listening.

It is best to ask one question at a time.

As for your second question, unless you are using some sort of "remote syncing" framework, that sort of behavior is unexpected. I would suggest posting a separate question for that issue with more details about it.